# unable to connect express.js with oracledb

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, express, node-modules

I am connecting Oracle database using express.js.

```
oracledb.getConnection(config, function (err, connection) {
  if (err) console.log(err);    
  connection.execute("SELECT * FROM database", function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({
        status: false,
        message: "there are some error with query"
      })
    } else {
      if(results !="" && results!= null && results!= undefined){
        res.json({
          data: results,
          status: true,
          message: "Data get from db"
        })
      }
    }
  })
})
```

The problem is that when I am running API I got the following error in cmd:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined'

So after getting this error, I have searched and I got a solution. Then I change my code in the following way:

```
(async function () {
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: 'xyz',
      password: 'xyz',
      connectString: 'xyz'
    });
    result = await connection.execute("SELECT * FROM database");
    res.json({
      data: result,
      status: true,
      message: "Data get from db",
      length: results.length
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close(); // Always close connections
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

But after implementing this asynchronous way, I got another errro:

> can not locate oracle 64bit client library: "some path.../oci.dll is not the correct architecture"...
>   UnhandledPromisePejectionWarning: connection is not defined....
>   UnhandledPromisePejectionWarning: this error is originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch, block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Oracle client installed?

Comment: yes. it's installed.

Comment: See this series for help getting started with creating REST APIs on Oracle Database with Node.js: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions as per your platform? https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html

Comment: @DanMcGhan ..npm install oracledb --save will work the same right? it will save all the oracledb dependencies on my current project.

Comment: No, this module has an external dependency, Oracle Instant Client, that must be installed separately.

Comment: dropped the idea of nodejs...now making APIs in asp .net. hehehehe